# Trying to make a java thread that checks if a list's size is larger than x while the main program keeps adding elements to the list

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

So the basic idea is this: I have a class called Testing, and in that class, there is an ArrayList of strings. I start a new thread that his sole purpose is to die when the size of the list in my Testing object exceeds the size of 10, while the main program keeps adding Strings to the list. For some reason I am stuck with an infinite loop on the main program, meaning the thread isn't dying.

Here is the code for the thread class

```
public class TestingThread implements Runnable{                                           
    public Testing t;                          

    public TestingThread(Testing t) {                                  
        this.t = t;                                  
    }                                                  

    @Override                                          
    public void run() {                                
        while(true){                                   
            if(t.words.size() > 10) break;            
        }                                              
    }                                                  
}
```

All thats important in the Testing class is that it has a public property List words.

This is what I am trying in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testing t = new Testing();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new TestingThread(t));
    myThread.start();

    while(true){
        if(!myThread.isAlive()) break;
        t.words.add("hello");
        System.out.println("adding...");
    }
    System.out.println(ts.words.toString());

    // joining the thread to the main thread at the end of the code
    try {  
        myThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("something went wrong");
    }
}
```

The myThread.isAlive() always returns true, so that means that the thread never finished it's while loop, meaning it fails to identify the size of the list have exceeded beyond 10. I can't find a solution for this. any suggestions? should I change my approach on this?

Comment: there is an error I see in the code.
`new TestingThread(0, t)`, what this first argument.
Other than that it should work as expected.

Comment: I fixed that, it was a typo when I typed everything here it was not on the main code. For some reason, it works once in a while, but most of the time it's just an infinite loop... any other ideas?

Comment: If there's no synchronization between the two threads, there's no guarantee your "testing thread" sees the changes made from main thread. Can you post the full program, including the"testing" class?